# Font shape undefined (error, not warning) for Helvetica Condensed Oblique with TeXLive 2020 & Catalina; worked fine in TeXLive 2017

Tags: fonts, texlive-2020, helvetica

Trying to use Helvetica Condensed Roman is fine, but Helvetica Condensed Oblique gives a hard error `undefined font shape OT1/phv/mc/sl` using TeXLive 2020 on MacOS 10.15 (Catalina). This worked fine on TeXLive 2017.

Running `pdflatex` (version: 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020)) on this MWE gives error at "this doesn't work" :

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\fontfamily{phv}\fontseries{mc}\selectfont
This works,
\textit{this doesn't work}
\end{document}
```

While running the MWE, I also see four **warnings** for file `/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1phv.fd`:

```
LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 21.
```

The warnings seem to be clearly related to the error, and while the `.fd` file does seem to have `\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{phv}{mc}{sl}{<-> \Hv@@scale phvro7tn}{}`, my TeX-font-fu is just not strong enough to figure out what is going on here.

Any insights appreciated, including switching to a similar font, fixing/replacing `.fd` file, whatever.

*Update:* @UlrikeFischer had the right suggestion.  I was surprised that it worked because I had downloaded the MacOS-specific MacTeX (.pkg) installer for TeXLive 2020. I uninstalled it, and then reinstalled using the Wish/Perl script (.tar.gz Unix-flavored) installer, which comes with the updated `.fd` files.  Beware if you're installing TeXLive on MacOS using MacTeX!

Comment: works ok for me. Is you system up-to-date? there was an update of psnfss some months ago,  ot1phv.fd should have the date  2020/03/25.

Comment: Yikes. My `.fd` file has the date 2001-06-04 if i'm reading it correctly:

Comment: So, update your distribution.The current .fd file contains `2020/03/25 scalable font definitions for OT1/phv`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you're right. The MacTeX installer for TeXLive 2020 has outdated .fd files; the .tar.gz based installer for same, which runs fine on MacOS if you give it the right privileges, includes the 2020-updated font files.